# Children book about a boy lost in the forest during a snow storm

Tags: identification-request, book-collecting

I don’t remember much about the book, but the illustrations where very pretty, they looked like they were painted by aquarela.
If I ain’t wrong the story was about a boy that got lost in a forest during the winter and he stayed with animals or maybe dwarfs during all winter till he could go back to is family.
I think my mother bought the book on lidl in the 2000’s

Comment: Aquarela = _water colour_.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The Tale of Jack Frost by David Melling maybe?